# easy c++ loop with pause but output is very weird!

Tags: c++, loops, timer

I'm just trying to write a program which outputs a series of numbers overwriting one another on the same line of the console screen. like 10 9 8 7 6 etc.

I'm using xcode and compiling in xcode. And this outputs "10 121469 121468", what am I doing wrong? Why doesn't it seem so obvious?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
#include <cstdlib>
#endif

int main()
{

  cout << "Description: This program will show you how much change" << endl;
  cout << "you will need to complete a transaction using a already" << endl;
  cout << "specified denomination" << endl << endl;

  cout << "CTRL=C to exit...\n";

  for (int units = 10; units > 0; units--)
  {
    cout << units << ' ';
    cout.flush();

#ifdef __GNUC__
    sleep(1); //one second
#elif defined _WIN32
    _sleep(1000); //one thousand milliseconds
#endif

    cout << '/r'; // CR
  }

  return 0;
} //main
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "overwriting" each other? Normally it's not possible to "back up" on the output stream. For one thing, the escape sequence for a CR is \r, not /r.

Comment: @debracey: Actually, outputting the `\r` escape sequence (which apparently the OP has mistyped) on the console *returns* the cursor back to the beginning of the line. That's how the OP is "overwriting" the previous output on the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this answers your answer but I've seen that your `CR` is wrong.

```
cout << '/r'; // CR
```

is 2 characters (which is your `12146` printed on the screen). The correct value must be

```
cout << '\r'; // CR
```

Answer (score 4):

This line is wrong:

```
cout << '/r'; // CR
```

That's two characters, you want

```
cout << '\r'; // CR
```

Comment: I took more time to spotted it.

Answer (score 1):

On n*x I use the following ANSI escape code to delete the current line and move the cursor to the beginning.

```
\033[0F\033[2K
```

So you would use it in the following way:

```
cout << "\033[0F\033[2K" << units << endl;
```

On the following page you can peruse all the details:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences

There's also a link on that page for how to achieve similar effects for windows.