# C++ how to overwrite a character in console, return carriage to start of line doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, console, carriage-return, overwrite

My question is, how do I get the numbers 10 - 0 to print out on the same line, overwriting each other using either a WIN32 or GNUC compiler in a simple manner like my code below:

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
#include <cstdlib>
#endif

int main()
{

  cout << "CTRL=C to exit...\n";

  for (int units = 10; units > 0; units--)
  {
    cout << units << '\r';
    cout.flush();
#ifdef __GNUC__
    sleep(1); //one second
#elif defined _WIN32
    _sleep(1000); //one thousand milliseconds
#endif

    //cout << "\r";// CR

  }

  return 0;
} //main
```

But this only prints:

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

Comment: No other libraries can be used but which I specify. There must be a way right?

Comment: This is pretty much an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451826/easy-c-loop-with-pause-but-output-is-very-weird -- In the responses Midnighter gave you a decent suggestion of how to "back up" the output stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some really trivial modification (mostly just to clean it up and make it more readable):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <unistd.h>
#define pause(n) sleep(n)
#elif defined _WIN32
#include <cstdlib>
#define pause(n) _sleep((n)*1000)
#endif

int main()
{

  cout << "CTRL=C to exit...\n";

  for (int units = 10; units > -1; units--)
  {
    cout << setw(2) << setprecision(2) << units << '\r';
    cout.flush();
    pause(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This worked fine with both VC++ and Cygwin. If it's not working under mingw, it sounds to me like an implementation problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use ncurses or another library for this, there is no standarized way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the backspace `'\b'` character?